# Verify Wordpress nonce in a Add Custom Post Type form

Tags: wordpress, nonce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I've created a Custom Post Type (CPT) and I've added a field group using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to WordPress. On the Add CPT screen, there is a hidden "_wpnonce" field in the form and I'm trying to verify that and manipulate some $_POST data. Is it possible to do?

I've tried to use `wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'], 'editpost' );`, which fails. I've also tried passing 'post.php' as the action, and leaving the action arg off. And I've tried using `$_POST` data instead of `$_REQUEST`.

I'm not sure if I'm able to verify that nonce, or if I'm supposed to somehow insert my own nonce into the Add.. page to verify against.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Have you created a custom form on the frontend that you're trying to validate a nonce for? Or are you trying to validate a nonce somewhere in the admin? If so that is probably unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining things well. I'm trying to validate the nonce in the admin area in the autogenerated add CPT form. TBH I'm trying to get this done due to an error reported by PHP Code sniffer and its making me twitch having an error.

Comment: I'm going to put this as a comment rather than an answer because I'm not sure that I can completely solve your problem (at least without knowing how you're adding your CPT - e.g. CPT UI plugin etc?)

What I can say is this; If you add a nonce with the following function: `wp_nonce_field('nonce-action', 'nonce-name')` you should be able to verify it like so: `wp_verify_nonce('nonce-action', 'nonce-name')`.

If i were you, check the name and action that the nonce is created with. Also you shouldn't need to use $_REQUEST... just pass the nonce name as a string.

Comment: @Basti, thanks for your help. I've added my CPT using regitster_post_type() and hooking into the the init() action. This is the crux of my probem: I'm not sure how I'd add the nonce field (using `wp_nonce_field()` ) as the add new CPT form seems to be generated by wp. Maybe I need create my own Add new CPT form and add it to the Admin menu? I was only using the `$_REQUEST['_wpnonce']` as I noticed it in the superglobals and thought that I could verify with it.

Comment: If you're not using a plugin to register custom post types, I'm not sure where you are getting a CPT form from. Do you simply mean the "Add new post" form for a custom post type? e.g. post.php?post_type={custom_post_type}. Or did you also create a form to add new custom post types?

Comment: Yes, I mean Add new {cpt}, which uses post.php.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191953/discussion-between-basti-and-damask).